# An object is being treated as NoneType in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, object, nonetype

There is a class Tree234 which has just one member _pRoot, which is a Node type object. The Node here itself is a class.

Now, when I am trying to use _pRoot directly in any method of the Tree234 class, it is working. But when I try to use it via a temporary variable equating it to _pRoot, it isn't working.

Below is the relevant piece of code:

```
class Tree234:
    #_pRoot = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._pRoot = Node()

    def find(self, key):
        pass

    def insert(self, dValue):
        pCurNode = self._pRoot
        pTempItem = DataItem(dValue)

        while True:
            if pCurNode.isFull():
                self.split(pCurNode)
                pCurNode = pCurNode.getParent()
                pCurNode = self.getNextChild(pCurNode, dValue)

            elif pCurNode.isLeaf():
                break

            else:
                pCurNode = self.getNextChild(pCurNode, dValue)
        pCurNode.insertItem(pTempItem)
```

The very first statement in the insert() isn't doing what it should do. When the control reaches the first statement in the while loop I am encountered with the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isFull'

And if I just replace the first statement within the while loop with this one (just to test):

```
if self._pRoot.isFull():
```

It accepts the attribute and moves forward (to raise the same error for other such statements, like the one in elif condition here)

So it's clear here that `pCurNode` is treated as None type, instead of the fact that I am assigning it to a Node type object using the statement `pCurNode = self._pRoot`

It's been a couple of hours I am trying to figure it out and still I don't have the slightest idea what's going in here. So decided to ask you fellas.
I know there is a something very silly here, that is causing the problem. But can't figure it out.

Can you find the problem here?

Comment: So what do `pCurNode.getParent()` and `self.getNextChild(pCurNode, dValue)` return? One of those returned `None`, after which you loop back to the `while` loop and you get your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(adding comment as answer)

you should check if `pCurNode is not None`  in the `while` clause like this: `while pCurNode:` or `while pCurNode is not None:` this is your problem.

This happens because the loop might not exit in a leaf, and this statement

```
else:
   pCurNode = self.getNextChild(pCurNode, dValue)
```

can fail to find any next child.

Similarly for the other statements where the node can fail to find any next child or parent (thus returning a `None`-like value).

Finaly before inserting check like this:

```
if pCurNode and pCurNode.isLeaf():  # insert data here
```

Comment: This would be the likely culprit, I believe the OP is assuming this is occurring on the first iteration of the loop, the more likely answer being that the getNextChild() or getParent() method is returning None.

Comment: @Nate, exactly however he states that when tested with the variable directly it works and fails afterwards

Comment: Right, yep missed that, so that's what he is assuming, +1 on this answer, this is the most likely cause of his issue.

Comment: @NikosM. Your guess was right, the loop wasn't exiting in the leaf block, because of a basic flaw in the isLeaf().
That was a naive mistake :-/
Just corrected that code and corrected all other bugs, now my Tree234 is flourishing :)
Thanks